# Multiline UIStackView / Break line if necessaries Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, uibutton, multiline, uistackview

I'd like to create some buttons (or UILables) and list them in a line and if necessaries, it breaks line automatically. Just like this image :

**what I want**

[image: what I want]

So, as I use IOS 9+, I've added a UIStackView and inside it I've added my buttons, but I have no new line definition in UIStackView. Do you have any have any idea or solution for my problem?

For now, my UIStackView is :

**What I have**

[image: What I have]

Comment: Why you put me negative point on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some Horizontal Stack Views into one Vertical Stack View just like this image :

[image]